# Suite 400 - 100 ABCDEF (Capture values from 100)

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I need a regular expression that would find `100 ABCDEF` from input string `Suite 400 - 100 ABCDEF`. It should be noted that I created a regex as below but it picks the value from Suite.

```
[^-\s]\d.+
```

Comment: Sure, just give us the logic behind how we should match `100 ABCDEF`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: Also please tell us which regex tool/language you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies folks and excuse me with my limited knowledge of regex. Basically, i'm extracting OCR data from an unstructured document and it returns a suite/unit number as prefix in front of any address. Basically I have a dictionary which stores street names across North America and I'm trying to find values like:

123 ABC Street
123 ABC Avenue
Suite 123 - 123 ABC Rd (In this string, I only intend to match 123 ABC Rd)

As far as the street names are concerned, I have a dictionary that matches it.
 [^-\s]\d.+DictionaryMatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `$` at the end of your regex. `$` means "end of line".
Also, replace the dot with `[^-]`, so it will match only non-hyphens:

```
[^-\s]?\d[^-]+$
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it works in most scenarios but I noticed that the following type fails: 5 ABC Bay SW.

Comment: Additionally, certain addresses like 1 123 Abc Street also pick 1 123 instead of just 123.

Comment: I thought the hyphen (actually a minus sign) were mandatory. 
Or, to handle this, just put a `?` after the first character class (which contains the minus sign). This will make it optional. I've updated the answer and the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks alex, your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to match a US street address, you should try matching a number followed by one or more words instead:

```
\d+(?:\s+[A-Za-z.]+)+
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/y6n5jD/1